# Jquery: change css selector on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I just get {"error": "Please use POST request"} when I run this

```
$("#ricomporreclick").click(function () {
    $("#film").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#ricomporre").css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

What's wrong with the code? I'm tring to change  the selector without page being reloaded.. when the click is triggered #film should be display:none and #ricomporre should be visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Ndba/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default functionality of the anchor tag,

```
$("#ricomporreclick").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $("#film").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#ricomporre").css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ndba/2/)

Comment: @DioCane Just now checked your page, Wrap that code inside `$(document).ready()`.! And let me know whether it is working or not.?

Answer (score 2):

just put `return false` at end of the code block.

[**Updated Your Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/D6sHy/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your anchor so the URL doesn't do anything:

```
<a href="javascript:void()" id="ricomporreclick">HERE</a>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/8Ndba/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the link from redirecting by using the preventDefault method. I've edited the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ndba/5/) to show this

```
$("#ricomporreclick").click(function (e) {
    $("#film").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    $("#ricomporre").css('visibility', 'visible');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

What was happening previously was that it was correctly changing the visibility, but then the link was reloading the page causing the css to be reset to the stylesheet.